# removing url parameters from one url using .htaccess codes

Tags: .htaccess

I tried lot of combinations using available examples (.htaccess directives), but I couldn't able to achieve what I want. The problem is...

My actual URL is 
`http://localhost/smon2/custsms/index.php?p_mob=9886419001`

What I want is
`http://localhost/smon2/custsms/`

Please help me in wrinting .htaccess code lines.
Thanks

I tried with few of the items below...

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p_mob=1$
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=permanent]

RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "p_mob=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /$1? [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^/custsms/%{QUERY_STRING}/?$  http : //localhost/smon2/custsms/ [NC,L]
```

Nothing was working. please help.

Comment: @anubhava added the code in the question itself. the comment section formating the into unreadable block.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve here - why not simply use the URL  `http://localhost/smon2/custsms/`?

Comment: ok good, where is this .htaccess located? Is it under `/smon2/` directory?

Comment: yes it is located in smon2 directory.

Comment: My objective is, any mobile number pass to this page will open a form, based on $_REQUEST['p_mob'], this should happen only once. when I submit the form the URL should not contain the parameter, so that form opening event will not occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all your current rules with this rule:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /smon2/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p_mob=\d+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(custsms)/index\.php$ $1/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, now I get error object not found as the URL turn into http://localhost/custsms

Comment: this url works fine as expected but when I enter http://localhost/smon2/custsms/index.php?p_mob=9886419001 it turns to http://localhost/custsms.  Since there is no such file/directory getting 404 error.

Comment: Ah fixed it now. Try my updated rule after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Cool. it works. but my $_REQUEST is empty now. is it possible to catch th p_mob value in some variable to further process in php?

Comment: No, once URL has been redirected to this one without any query parameter you cannot retrieve `p_mob` back.